# How to avoid a form being resubmitted in node.js / express / multer when there's no response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, multer

I have a problem in that sometimes my form (submitted in a standard way via the Node.Js app) takes too long to be processed.

On the backend (app.js) the logic looks like this:

```
var multer = require('multer')
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './temp')
    },
    filename: function(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.originalname)
    },
})

var upload = multer({ 
    storage: storage
})
app.post(
    '/import',
    upload.array('uploadedFiles', 50),
    imports.submit
)
```

So what happens then is that the POST request happens again (probably after not receiving any response) and the files get resubmitted. My log shows `/POST --/--`.

How can I avoid having that happen?

I tried to use the following code:

```
 

        $('#submitform').on('submit', function(e){

            e.preventDefault();   
            

            $(this).find('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $('#message').html('Importing the data');
            
            $("#submitform").unbind('submit').submit()
            

        });
```

But it simply does not submit the form.

How could I fix this issue?

I can't use AJAX as the response I get from the node.js app as I'd have to rewrite too much backend.

Comment: Forms usually don't send themselves on their own. There is probably a callback somewhere that does not catch an error and the process is continued like no error happened. We cannot know for sure since you've provided a limited subset of your code but, i'd look for something like that.

Comment: In chrome, there is a tab that shows the _initiator_ of your request. You could check, on your second request ( the one you don't want ), where it comes from and then try to fix that behaviour.

Comment: @Nicolas in the backend I simply use this code below and I think automatically when it doesn't receive a response after a certain time it simply submits the form again...

Comment: ```app.post(
    '/import',
    upload.array('uploadedFiles', 50),
    imports.submit
)```

Comment: If it does that automatically, there probably a way to turn it off. I'm not sure what would cause that, but i know it's not a native feature your browser.